# SQL aggregate get monthly and yearly

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I am trying to get aggregate for monthly total and add extra row for yearly total into same SQL query.

```
Table table_1

id    date        amount   currency

 1    2017-01-01  76.89     CAD
 2    2017-01-17  90.89     CAD
 3    2017-01-18  65        USD
 4    2017-05-13  45        CAD
 5    2017-07-19  76.70     CAD
 6    2018-08-13  67.34     CAD
 7    2018-09-11  50        CAD
 8    2018-09-09  45        CAD
 9    2018-08-12  67        CAD
 10   2018-07-10  55        USD
 11   2018-07-11  13        USD
```

I have tried with this query getting total monthly and group by currency.

```
    SELECT SUM(amount),
           currency, 
           MONTH(date)
   FROM invoices 
   GROUP BY MONTH(date), YEAR(date), currency
```

Prototype of result which I want

[prototype of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wsSd.png)

Thank you

Comment: What is wrong with your query? Can you add a prototype of the result you would expect?

Comment: Look at `ROLLUP`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: @Fabio I have added prototype of result in which format I want it.

Comment: @Fabio I have again edited my question for prototype. result can be different but something like that

Comment: @PM77-1 I think ROLLUP will not work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rows for the whole years contain the `NULL` value in the month column

```sql
SELECT MONTH(date) AS Month,
       YEAR(date) AS Year,
       currency AS Currency,
       SUM(amount) AS Total
FROM invoices 
GROUP BY MONTH(date), YEAR(date), currency
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, YEAR(date), currency, SUM(amount)
FROM invoices 
GROUP BY YEAR(date), currency
ORDER BY Year, Month IS NULL, Month
```

You can find a demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4eaf7177d6916ff69cca88427fe0fbde)

EDIT: ordered the result set as for requirement

EDIT2: I still don't understand why the solution was not acceptable before, I tweaked it a bit to make it coincide with the new prototype of the result

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I want to add extra row for total of that year not combining two different data

Comment: @user987 The problem of this solution is the ordering of the rows or the presence of the year in the rows containing the total amount of the month?

Comment: It is ordering it should be after each not all together.

Comment: I mean not `order by` but 2017 should be after showing all 2017 data and 2018 should be after showing all 2018 data

Comment: @user987 You said that the presence of the year in the rows containing the total amount of the month is not a problem, the query returns a result similar to the one shown in the prototype as you asked, can you elaborate the reasons why the solution is not acceptable?

Comment: I have edit question and added prototype image for more information

Comment: @user987 keep in mind that the use of images is discouraged on stackoverflow.

Comment: @user987 also notice this solution is useful for certain reasons for future operations on the obtained dataset. If what you need is just an appealing visual result you can simply replace `NULL` with `'Total'` in the query.

Answer (score 2):

The order you `SELECT` columns or `ORDER` them can be different from the order you `GROUP` them.

Then you can use `GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP` and check what's a super-aggregate using `GROUPING()` for both choosing what levels to aggregate to, and what order to display everything.

```
SELECT
   YEAR(date),
   MONTH(date),
   currency,
   SUM(amount)
FROM
   invoices
GROUP BY
   currency,
   YEAR(date),
   MONTH(date)
WITH
   ROLLUP
HAVING
   GROUPING(Currency) = 0  -- don't ROLLUP the currency
ORDER BY
   GROUPING(YEAR(date)),  -- individual years first, super-aggregate last
   YEAR(date),
   GROUPING(MONTH(date)), -- individual months first, super-aggregate last
   MONTH(date),
   currency
```